# getting a html page with SVG that works in ubuntu to display correctly in windows on firefox 5

Tags: windows, firefox, svg

I'm trying to get this page to display its SVG content correctly in Firefox 5 in Windows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>SVG Rich Text Editor</title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        ...
    </style>
    <script>
        var gui //define a global varaible to pass it on between frames
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="toolbar" src ="toolbar.html" width="500px" height="50px" frameBorder="0"></iframe><br/>    
    <iframe id="editor" src="editor.svg" width="500px" height="500px" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

it works perfectly in Ubuntu but in Windows (Vista) when loading the page Firefox 5 asks me if I want to open or download the file instead of displaying it.

I've also tried it by using an object tag instead of an iframe tag. Again it works perfectly in Ubuntu but in Windows it wants to download a plug-in, which I don't mind except it doesn't find any.

I've checked and the HTML5 parser is automatically enabled in this version so that can't be it.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

EDIT 3:

After changing my local server to print the header instead of doing the default get I get this when loading http://localhost:8000/editor.svg:

```
Host: localhost:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:6.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
```

this is the top of in editor.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

small note: there is some java script and css inside of the editor.

EDIT 4

I've created a small python program based on the one provided in the python documentation (http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#examples)  and asked for editor.svg
to get the response header:

```
'date': 'Sat, 20 Aug 2011 13:30:57 GMT'
'last-modified': 'Thu, 18 Aug 2011 11:34:42 GMT'
'content-length': '1986'</br>
'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
'server': 'SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.2'
```

I believe we have now confirmed it sees the svg as an application rather then an image. Question is how do you solve this? Preferably by adding some information in the svg itself instead of messing with the server.

Comment: Check the MIME type that gets sent along with the .svg. How are you hosting it? Local filesystem? Web server running on localhost?

Comment: Can you display the image alone (i.e. just by typing its URL in the address bar)?

Comment: @henning: very good comment i checked when doing http://localhost:8000/editor.html it wants to download it , when typing the full path it works

Comment: @tdammers : how do i check the MIME type that gets sent along ?

Comment: You can use curl, for example - `curl -iI url`. Doesn't work if you open the page from a local filesystem.

Comment: @tdammers i've tried curl -iI http://localhost:8000/editor.html and http://localhost:8000/editor.svg both time out.  does it has anything to do with local file system (i'm not sure if you mean only using the actual file path will fail or if the simple fact that the file is on the pc makes it fail) or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: @Danny: you'll have to add `http://` to the url to tell curl which protocol to use, and you need to have an actual web server (apache, IIS, lighttpd...) running. If you open the file directly from a local filesystem (i.e., through a `file://` URL), then the MIME types will be derived from the file types. Ubuntu and Windows do this differently, which might explain the problem.

Comment: Regarding your edits: The Accept header should contain something that matches SVG (if only */*), otherwise your web server might helpfully change the MIME type. Can't really tell without the *response* headers though.

Comment: @tdammers  i did use http:// if forgot to write it; how do i get the response header then ? i suppose its not on my webservers end ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your local web server is sending the wrong MIME type for .svg files on Windows.  What type is it sending?

Comment: tdammers said the same thing and it sounds interesting, but i have no idea how to check it. so if you could tell me how i'll let you know

Comment: Well, a simple way is to use Firebug or Live HTTP Headers to look at the server response in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Since SVG is a graphics format, have you tried simply using

```
<img src="editor.svg" width="500px" height="500px">
```

Comment: tnx for answering, that doesn't work either. it after the toolbar iframe everything is white. the firebug console tells me (not as an error but simply when i go over the element) that it couldn't load the image